# Sending binaries or strings by a client socket

Tags: go

I'm studying networks, and I'm doing a tcp server with Go. One of the challenges I'm studying is to send binaries or strings by a socket client to a server, save the server response to a txt, and compare it to the original data that was sent.

The problem is that the binaries do not arrive completely on the server.

**Server**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8000")
    if nil != err {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer l.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if nil != err {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        defer conn.Close()
        go ConnHandler(conn)
    }
}

func ConnHandler(conn net.Conn) {
    recvBuf := make([]byte, 4096)
    for {
        n, err := conn.Read(recvBuf)
        if nil != err {
            if io.EOF == err {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        if 0 < n {
            data := recvBuf[:n]
            fmt.Println(string(data))
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":8000")
    if nil != err {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    var s string
    fmt.Scanln(&s)
    conn.Write([]byte(s))

    conn.Close()
}
```

I'm generating the binaries using the command on linux:

```
head -c100000 /dev/urandom > binary_message.txt
```

I run the server:

```
./server > result.txt
```

And I send this data by the client using:

```
./client < binary_data.txt
```

In the end the file binary_data.txt have 98KB but the result .txt only has 0KB.

Comment: Have you tried running the server without piping the output to a file?

Comment: Hi. Yeah, I got this: ...some binary here...
2021/01/16 19:50:30 EOF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with scanning the binary from input. You didn't see it because the errors were ignored and not printed or otherwise handled. `fmt.Scanln` returns an error (so does the `Write` function). You should always check for possible errors happening.

I rewrote the client to load the file from disk itself as I don't think using stdin is a good fit for binary data.

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

var fileName = flag.String("file", "", "file to send")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":8000")
    if nil != err {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    f, err := os.Open(*fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    b := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := f.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                log.Println("Done sending")
                return
            }
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }

        if _, err := conn.Write(b[:n]); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }

}
```

You can use it with:

```sh
go run . -file=binary_message.txt
```

or if you have built the binary:

```sh
./client -file=binary_message.txt
```

I suggest you do the same for the server. Open a file for writing and write the binary data into that file. Use a flag to pass in the filename to write to. That will be cleaner than piping stdout to a file.